# Can I restore a table with flashback database even if I used "drop table purge"?

Tags: oracle-12c, flashback

If I issue the following statement:
drop table DontDrop purge;

It's going to be flushed out of my recycle bin so flashback statement won't work:

```
select * from DontDrop as of timestamp to_timestamp(sysdate-1);
```

Now, can I use a flashback database statement to restore it?

```
flashback database to timestamp (sysdate-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Flashback database can be used to restore a dropped table that is no longer in the recyclebin.

Provided the following is true:

1) Flashback database is turned on which you can check via:

`select flashback_on from v$database;`

2) You have the flashback logs to flashback that far, which you can check via:

`select oldest_flashback_time from v$flashback_database_log;`.

3) You have the backup archived redo/archived redo on disk to flashback the database that far.

The syntax looks like the following:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
FLASHBACK DATABASE TO TIME 'SYSDATE-1';
startup open resetlogs;
```

The Oracle Database 12c docs about flashback database can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9011.htm#SQLRF01801).